# Lightbox Overlay doesn't scroll down in Chrome or Edge

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, overlay, lightbox

I have an issue with my wordpress website which uses the Lightbox (WP Lightbox 2)plugin and the overlay it creates. More specifically when I click on the image in Firefox the overlay appears right where the scroll is, fitting the browser. But if I click on the image in Chrome or Edge, the overlay stays on top of the page and does not scroll down for some reason. 
If it was just css, I would be able to fix it, but it seems that "top" value for lightbox class is defined via js somehow and I have no idea what causes that difference. Right now it is different in Firefox - adding a proper amount of "space" on top, and in Chrome it doesn't add anything but a regular padding value. So the whole thing sits on top.
Obviously I need to have a lightbox overlay open where the scroll is on the page, not just on top.

Here is the link to the page you can try it on, just scroll down and click on the images in Chrome and if Firefox and you will see what I mean.

http://mnabievart.com/deck-of-card-design/

Comment: I can see $ is not a function error on console

Comment: That was unrelated. I figured out the issue might be with JS top offset of some sort. I saw people posting about it, but I'm too weak in JS to figure it out. Here is a direct link to lightbox's JS file, maybe you could figure it out how to make it cross browser?  http://mnabievart.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-lightbox-2/wp-lightbox-2.min.js

Comment: you can contact plugin author

Comment: I just installed another Lightbox and the same issue occurs. it all works perfect on local server. But if I upload it on live web server, it breaks. Lightboxes just stay on top all the time. I don't understand what's wrong, my local files and server files are identical!

Comment: the lightboxgallery class not removed after close the popup from body tag.

Comment: you remove the class from body on this function call 'onCloseAfter: function () {remove code}'

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. It all works perfectly locally and is stuck on top of the page on server and there are no errors in the console. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: click on the image there was a class added in body tag. after closing the popup the class was not removed. so you need to remove the class

Comment: but why is it working on localhost then? Also, I didn't change anything in plugins and I tried three different plugins, all result in the same issue, I'm sure it's not because of that

Comment: did you try http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ plugin?

Comment: .lightGallery {    overflow: visible !important;} add this style and try

Comment: Yes, looks like it did something at least! Now there is that weird grey top bar there for some reason, but at least the image shows up as needed!

Comment: yes. you can set #lightGallery-outer{top:-50px}. bcoz somewhere top 50px added

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style and try

```
.lightGallery {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

and

```
#lightGallery-outer{
   top:-50px
}
```